# Counting how many elements in a sorted list, that are larger than a given predicate

Tags: sml

I'm trying to create a function that finds how many elements that are bigger than the first element divided by `2` in a given sorted list. For example given a list `[3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11]`, first element is `3`, numbers larger divided by `2` are `7,8,9,11` so function returns `4`.

I have done this so far but it doesn't work. The `a` element is the first of the list and is given in order to be easier.

```
fun findlarger a [] =
  | findlarger [] = 0
  | findlarger [x] = 0
  | findlarger (x::xs) =
    let
      val a = ref a;
    in
      if !a < x/2 then length (xs) + 1 else findlarger (a, xs)
    end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't even know where to start pointing out issues with your code. It seems that you have misunderstood the basics of functional programming.

- First off you should not be using references (unless you know what you are doing, at then its probably still wrong), you should use recursion.
- You haven't declared your function to take the same number of arguments. In the first clause, you have defined it with 2 curried arguments, in the rest of the clauses you only have one argument, and in the second last line of code, you are calling the function with a pair as argument.
- Your first function clause don't have a body.
- `"<"` is not the strictly less than operator in sml. As you have written it there, it is a string.

Fixing your original code will result in something like this. Note that the first element is always put back into the list, such that we know what to compare with.

```
fun findlarger [] = 0
  | findlarger [x] = 0
  | findlarger (x::y::xs) =
    if y > x*2 then
      1 + findlarger(x :: xs)
    else
      findlarger(x :: xs)
```

However you could also have made it with a internal helper function and done the calculation of x*2, so that won't be calculated every time

```
fun findlarger [] = 0
  | findlarger (x::xs) =
    let
      val xx = 2*x
      fun f [] = 0
        | f (y::ys) =
          (if y > xx then 1 else 0) + f ys
    in
      f xs
    end
```

If using the higher order functions as suggested in the other answer, then you should avoid traversing the list twice (first by filtering out elements and then counting the remaining). You should just go through the list once, and count the elements that match a given predicate.
To accomplish this functionality, you may use one of the fold functions. In most cases it makes sense to use foldl, as it will traverse the list from left to right in a tail recursive manner.

```
fun p (x, y) = if y > 2*x then 1 else 0

fun f [] = 0
  | f (x::xs) = foldl (fn (a,b) => b + p(x, a)) 0 xs
```

Comment: This solution works fine for small integers,but some testcases have large ints and it throws an error uncaught exception Overflow [overflow].A friend of mine pointed that the problem is in 2*x. He says I should do the comparison not like this y<2*x but x/2>y but this has other problems because it must be reals and there must be some round up in order to achieve the comparison..

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
fun find lst =
    case lst of
        [] => 0
      | x::_ => List.length(List.filter(fn e => e > 2 * x) lst)
```

Usage:

```
find [3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11] => 4
```

Comment: sadly you just hand him a solution, without explaining why it works, or even worse explaining why his original code doesn't do the job.

Comment: @Jesper.Reenberg I think solution is pretty obvious for giving explanation